# Remove CDATA from XML

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I am working on a SOAP api with python-suds.

Api returns result and suds parse it according to WSDL. result data have an XML data field

```
(MyServiceResult){
    errorMsg = "Error Message here..."
    sessionId = "..."
    outputDataXML = "<![CDATA[<Results>.....<Details>....</Details></Results>]]>"
    errorCode = "00"
 }
```

So I planned to use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the xml data part `outputDataXML`. But since returning data starts with `<![CDATA[`, xml parser fails with

> **ParseError:** syntax error: line 1, column 0

What is the best approach for a such situation except usge of regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `ET.fromstring` once to extract the text from the CDATA. Call `ET.fromstring` a second time to parse the string as XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

d = '<![CDATA[<Results>.....<Details>....</Details></Results>]]>'
fix = '<root>{}</root>'.format(d)

content = ET.fromstring(fix).text
print(repr(content))
# '<Results>.....<Details>....</Details></Results>'

results = ET.fromstring(content)
print(ET.tostring(results))
# <Results>.....<Details>....</Details></Results>
```

Comment: Even this solution uses a fix, it looks better than installing extra python packages (I do not have BeautifulSoup and have to set it up for @mguijarr's Bs solution)

Answer (score 1):

When reading all kind of weird formatted XML-like data, you can always use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> d="<![CDATA[<Results>.....<Details>....</Details></Results>]]>"
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(d)
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> tree=ElementTree.fromstring(str(soup))
```

Otherwise, you can make a quick hack like this:

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(outputDataXML.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", ""))
```

Comment: Using BeautifulSoup causes all tags to became lowercase. Since I an dealing with an xml, this behaviour is unwanted. using xml parser `BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")` fails since there is no valid xml header in the result text.  [Here is related docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems)